# Parallel the particle swarm optimization in Julia

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, julia

I wrote the particle swarm optimization algorithm in Julia, and I tried to use Threads to accelerate the computation for each population.
Here is the code

```
function uniform(dim::Int, lb::Array{Float64, 1}, ub::Array{Float64, 1})
    arr = rand(Float64, dim)
    @inbounds for i in 1:dim; arr[i] = arr[i] * (ub[i] - lb[i]) + lb[i] end
    return arr
end

function initialize_particles(problem, population)
    dim = problem.dim
    lb = problem.lb
    ub = problem.ub
    cost_func = problem.cost_func

    gbest_position = uniform(dim, lb, ub)
    gbest = Gbest(gbest_position, cost_func(gbest_position))

    particles = []
    for i in 1:population
        position = uniform(dim, lb, ub)
        velocity = zeros(dim)
        cost = cost_func(position)
        best_position = copy(position)
        best_cost = copy(cost)
        push!(particles, Particle(position, velocity, cost, best_position, best_cost))

        if best_cost < gbest.cost
            gbest.position = copy(best_position)
            gbest.cost = copy(best_cost)
        end
    end
    return gbest, particles
end

function PSO(problem; max_iter=100,population=100,c1=1.4962,c2=1.4962,w=0.7298,wdamp=1.0)
    dim = problem.dim
    lb = problem.lb
    ub = problem.ub
    cost_func = problem.cost_func

    gbest, particles = initialize_particles(problem, population)

    # main loop
    for iter in 1:max_iter
        @threads for i in 1:population
            particles[i].velocity .= w .* particles[i].velocity .+
                c1 .* rand(dim) .* (particles[i].best_position .- particles[i].position) .+
                c2 .* rand(dim) .* (gbest.position .- particles[i].position)

            particles[i].position .= particles[i].position .+ particles[i].velocity
            particles[i].position .= max.(particles[i].position, lb)
            particles[i].position .= min.(particles[i].position, ub)

            particles[i].cost = cost_func(particles[i].position)

            if particles[i].cost < particles[i].best_cost
                particles[i].best_position = copy(particles[i].position)
                particles[i].best_cost = copy(particles[i].cost)
        
                if particles[i].best_cost < gbest.cost
                    gbest.position = copy(particles[i].best_position)
                    gbest.cost = copy(particles[i].best_cost)
                end
            end
        end
        w = w * wdamp
        if iter % 50 == 1
            println("Iteration " * string(iter) * ": Best Cost = " * string(gbest.cost))
            println("Best Position = " * string(gbest.position))
            println()
        end
    end
    gbest, particles
end
```

Obviously, it is not thread-safe in main loop of PSO. This is because the position of gbest needs to be modified when computing.
I tried to use Atomic, but the position of each particle is an array. So this method is not suitable.
The Lock needs initialization, so it also won't work.
I also tried to use Floop, but it went wrong.

So is there a way to make sure the data is locked when doing parallel computation?

Thank you for your time!

Wang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to lock variables. When you are doing parallel calculations you can always think in the terms of Split-Combine strategy (sorry just invent this term in analogy with DataFrames calculation, you may also call it Map-Reduce approach). The idea is that you split calculations around different threads and do them independently and on the final stage you combine results together on a single thread. So your code can look like this (there can be syntax errors, since I can't run the code without `Particle` and other definitions, but I hope it is enough to give the idea)

```
function minby(itr; by=identity, init=nothing)
     init = isnothing(init) ? pop!(itr) : init
     mapreduce(x->(by(x)=>x), (x,y)->(first(x)>first(y)) ? y : x, itr; init=by(init)=>init).second
end

function PSO(problem; max_iter=100,population=100,c1=1.4962,c2=1.4962,w=0.7298,wdamp=1.0)
    dim = problem.dim
    lb = problem.lb
    ub = problem.ub
    cost_func = problem.cost_func

    gbest, particles = initialize_particles(problem, population)

    # main loop
    for iter in 1:max_iter
        gbests = fill((gbest.cost, 0), Threads.nthreads())
        @threads for i in 1:population
            particles[i].velocity .= w .* particles[i].velocity .+
                c1 .* rand(dim) .* (particles[i].best_position .- particles[i].position) .+
                c2 .* rand(dim) .* (gbest.position .- particles[i].position)

            particles[i].position .= particles[i].position .+ particles[i].velocity
            particles[i].position .= max.(particles[i].position, lb)
            particles[i].position .= min.(particles[i].position, ub)

            particles[i].cost = cost_func(particles[i].position)

            if particles[i].cost < particles[i].best_cost
                particles[i].best_position = copy(particles[i].position)
                particles[i].best_cost = copy(particles[i].cost)
        
                if particles[i].best_cost < gbests[Threads.threadid()][1]
                    gbests[Threads.threadid()] = (particles[i].best_cost, i)
                end
            end
        end
        gbest1 = minby(gbests, by = x -> x[1])
        if gbest1[2] != 0
            idx = gbest1[2]
            gbest.position = copy(particles[idx].best_position)
            gbest.cost = copy(particles[idx].best_cost)
        end
        w = w * wdamp
        if iter % 50 == 1
            println("Iteration " * string(iter) * ": Best Cost = " * string(gbest.cost))
            println("Best Position = " * string(gbest.position))
            println()
        end
    end
    gbest, particles
end
```

By the way, you may find that package [UnPack.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/UnPack.jl) is rather convinient. Instead of manual assignments, you can do just

```
using UnPack
function PSO(problem; max_iter=100,population=100,c1=1.4962,c2=1.4962,w=0.7298,wdamp=1.0)
    @unpack dim, lb, ub, cost_func = problem
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrej Oskin! I think I've got your idea. Just store the evaluated results from different threads in different places, then select the lowest fitness one as the global best. Although the calculation process is a little different from previous code. The previous one changes gbest each population, while the new code changes gbest each iteration.

Comment: Oh, by the way, Unpack package is good, but how do you find this type of packges? I knew a bunch of packages is quite useful, but they are not in the manual and just hide in the network. How do you know they can be useful for specific demands?

Comment: Unfortunately (or maybe, fortunately) Julia ecosystem is developing very fast, so there is no established set of packages "which everyone should know". Best way to stay tuned is to join community and not hesitate to ask: discourse, zulip and slack. You can find links here https://julialang.org/community/

Comment: Yes, this version update `gbest` once per population, but aren't that what you actually need? If `i+1` calculation depends on `i` than it can't be made parallel. Sorry, I do not know much about PSO.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Andrej Oskin! Oh, by the way. I ran the multi-thread version program above ten times to make sure I could obtain the minimum. And I noticed that the memory usage in my PC would fluctuate fiercely at first three or four running, then it would keep stable for the rest of running. The calculation speed is also faster for the rest of running. It seems that Julia found the operation pattern and then optimize the memory usage or garbage collection process. So I want to know could Julia optimize this calculation process automatically?

Comment: Julia compiles the program only once, but only when it is needed (it is called JIT - just-in-time compiling). Maybe some parts of your program were not hit on the first runs and this cause additional compiltations. Or maybe you have lots of garbage to be collected, so you saw GC from the previous run.

If you want to measure time properly, you should use [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl), which is Julia standard package for time measurments.